# Unexpected opening curly bracket indentation

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, resharper, code-formatting

If I type `if (true)` <kbd>Enter</kbd>

the cursor will be indented like

[image: Cursor indented]

and if I continue with `{` <kbd>Enter</kbd> `}`, I will get a brace layout like

[image: unexpected brace layout]

Why?

I expect the braces to be like

[image: expected brace layout]

In resharpers *Braces layout* section I have setup braces layout to be *At next line (BSD style)*.

In visual studios options, going into Text Editor, C#, Code Style, Formatting, Indentation I have the checkbox *Indent open and close braces* checkbox unchecked.

How is it possible with two separate options sections for code style, both Visual Studio and Resharper? Who wins?

Comment: You should know that you are not alone in this struggle.  Oh, and if you have a solution, it is perfectly acceptable to answer your own question and then accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

I ***think*** the solution is to:

go to **Visual Studio Options** -> **Text Editor** -> **All Languages** -> **Tabs** and set **Indenting** to **Block**, then

go to **ReSharper Options** -> **Environment** -> **Editor** -> **Editor Behavior** and make sure **Smart Indent on Enter** is unchecked.

Comment: No, it isn't really. I mean it is, but then if you do this, several other code formatting behaviors which used to work just fine, are now broken.